# I can't find how to clear led alarm in juniper

Tags: command-line, juniper

How can I clear led alarm in my juniper after problem has been resolved? 
I find the command "clear led alarm", but in my CLI I have only:

```
root@EX2200-2501-03> clear l
                        ^
'l' is ambiguous. 
Possible completions:
  lacp                 Clear Link Aggregation Control Protocol information
  lldp                 Clear Link Layer Discovery Protocol information
  log                  Clear contents of log file
root@EX2200-2501-03> clear l
```

Where can I find "clear led alarm"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alarm will clear itself when you resolve the issues, typically.  Though I have seen it where the event wouldn't resolve until the switch was rebooted.

If the alarm hasn't resolved itself, are you sure there aren't other alarms on the system? (i.e. `request system configuration rescue save` ([here](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1/topics/task/operational/junos-software-rescue-configuration-file-saving.html)))